# Получить первое число каждого месяца заданного периода в цикле

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Как можно перебрать все месяцы заданного периода в цикле?

Например, период с `05.07.2012` по `09.10.2017`.

И получить первое число каждого месяца из этого периода:

```
(trunc(dt,'mm'))
```

Comment: В каком именно цикле и зачем этот цикл нужен. обычно проще получить требуемое прямо в запросе. А так то берете первое число периода и делаете add_months, пока не достигните даты окончания

Comment: В цикле pl/sql кода. Насчет цикла понял, забыл про while, уперся в for ))) Спасибо.

Comment: А что у вас уже получилось? "забыл про while" - покажите, что у вас в цикле.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так, как внутри функции. Здесь для наглядности с выводом в запросе:

```
create or replace function getFirstDaysOfMonth (rangeFrom date, rangeTo date) return sys.odciDateList pipelined is
begin
    for next in 0..months_between (rangeTo, rangeFrom) loop 
        pipe row (trunc (add_months (rangeFrom, next), 'mm')); 
    end loop;
    return;
end;
/

select to_char (column_value, 'dd.mm.yyyy') "firstDayOfMonth" 
from table (getFirstDaysOfMonth (date'2012-07-05', date'2017-10-09'))
;

firstDayOfMonth
---------------
01.07.2012
01.08.2012
...
01.09.2017
01.10.2017
```

Тот же результат одним запросом:

```
with params as (
    select date'2012-07-05' rangeFrom, date'2017-10-09' rangeTo 
from dual
)
select trunc (add_months (rangeFrom, level-1), 'mm') firstDayOfMonth
from params
connect by level-1 <= months_between (rangeTo, rangeFrom)
;
```